# Tell pgfplots not to try to plot where the function is not defined

Tags: pgfplots, plot

The following code raises error because the function is not defined on part of the domain (e.g. `acos` cannot have its argument greater than 1):

```tex
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\myfunc}[1]{acos(cos(sqrt(#1))+3*sin(sqrt(#1))/sqrt(#1))}
    \begin{axis}[xmax={pi},xmin={-pi},xlabel={$ka$},xtick distance={pi/2},
        xticklabels={,$-\pi$,$-\dfrac\pi2$,$0$,$\dfrac\pi2$,$\pi$},
        ymax=40,ymin=0,ytick={-10},ylabel={$E_k$},ylabel style={rotate=-90},
    trig format=rad]
        \addplot[domain=0:40,smooth,samples=100,variable=\x] ({\myfunc\x},{\x});
        \addplot[domain=0:40,smooth,samples=100,variable=\x] ({-\myfunc\x},{\x});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have to calculate the domain numerically.
This will work:

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\myfunc}[1]{acos(cos(sqrt(#1))+3*sin(sqrt(#1))/sqrt(#1))}
    \begin{axis}[xmax={pi},xmin={-pi},xlabel={$ka$},xtick distance={pi/2},
        xticklabels={,$-\pi$,$-\dfrac\pi2$,$0$,$\dfrac\pi2$,$\pi$},
        ymax=40,ymin=0,ytick={-10},ylabel={$E_k$},ylabel style={rotate=-90},
    trig format=rad]
        \addplot[domain=3.90648:9.8696,smooth,samples=20,variable=\x] ({\myfunc\x},{\x});
        \addplot[domain=18.916:39.4784,smooth,samples=50,variable=\x] ({\myfunc\x},{\x});
        \addplot[domain=3.90648:9.8696,smooth,samples=20,variable=\x] ({-\myfunc\x},{\x});
        \addplot[domain=18.916:39.4784,smooth,samples=50,variable=\x] ({-\myfunc\x},{\x});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Expected plot]

The numbers 3.90648, 9.8696 etc. are numerical results.
I do not like this because

- I have to hard-code the numerical values;
- The domain is two discontinued pieces, so I have to use two `\addplot` commands to plot all sections.

Is there a way I can let pgfplots just ignore the places where the function is not defined?

---

The points where the value of the function is complex are considered as out of domain, which I intend to omit (I just want to plot the real function).

The function is

$$x=\pm\arccos!\left(\cos\sqrt{y}+3\frac{\sin\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt y}\right).$$

The plot produced by specifying the segments above can be confirmed correct by compare it with the output generated by Mathematica:

```mathematica
f[y_]=ArcCos[Cos[Sqrt[y]]+3Sin[Sqrt[y]]/Sqrt[y]]
ParametricPlot[{{f[y],y},{-f[y],y}},{y,0,40},AspectRatio -> 0.7]
```

[image]

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small, compilable document. Explain what is your function (in LaTeX format). Does `rad` means radians or something else? Why you not use standard definition for plotting functions?

Comment: Your function seems to be complex.. Such functions cannot be present in 2-D real plane. What you show on image is fake.

Comment: The function is real, and the image is not fake because I plotted the function using other tools. The points where it is complex are considered out of the domain of the function, which I intend to omit as I said. `rad` means converting degree to radian, and this function is available as long as `pgfplots` package is imported so I did not explain it. I will add a complete compilable example soon.

Comment: I disagree with you. You compose your image for segments  drawn on two separated different domains (where function exist).  In domains between this segments apparently it is not defined. That function use radians you can tell to `pgfplots` width option `trig format = rad` in `axis` options and not use in your command definition.

Comment: I mean, it is indeed complex outside the segments, but I want pgfplots to just ignore those points (consider them out of domain). As a real function as I consider, the function is only defined on the segments I specified (and other segments where the function is real).

Comment: As I told you, image is fake. First you need to solve your math problem. Eventually you can draw it real and imaginary values separately.

Comment: The image is not fake. I edited the question and included a plot produced by Mathematica.

Comment: I am unsure why this does not work here. Maybe you can try to define a PGF function (see https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/utility-commands )? Actually, PGF knows if a value is `nan` (not a number) and this won't affect the plot (the coordinate will be ignored by default). This does not quite work here probably, as you use a parametric plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sagetex](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex) package gives access to an open source computer algebra system (CAS) called [Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/) along with the Python programming language. The CAS Sage is similar to Mathematica except it's free. As a result it will have the computational horsepower that `pgfplots` will not and the `sagetex` package lets you work Sage data and calculations into your LaTeX document.

You said, "The numbers 3.90648, 9.8696 etc. are numerical results. I do not like this because

- I have to hard-code the numerical values;
- The domain is two discontinued pieces, so I have to use two \addplot commands to plot all sections.

The approach using `sagetex` avoids hard-coding numerical values but it doesn't avoid 2 \addplot commands. I don't think this can be avoided because Mathematica is using 2 plots as well: `ParametricPlot[{{f[y],y},{-f[y],y}},{y,0,40},AspectRatio -> 0.7]`; the first piece consists of points (f(y),y) and the second piece is made of points (-f(y),y). Plotting f(y) from 0<y<=40 gives the right half of the graph so when I tried a direct plot it wanted to connect the upper half to the lower half:

[image]

As a result I tried plotting just points without connecting them. The result is shown below:

[image]

The result looks better but there are still issues near 0. You'll need to figure out what's acceptable to you. You can try increasing the size of the dots and/or adding more points by making the step size smaller. Here is the code shown in the second picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex,amsmath,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
t = var('t,y')
LowerY = 0
UpperY = 45
LowerX = -3.15
UpperX = 3.15
step = .01
########
xcoords1=[]
ycoords1=[]
xcoords2=[]
ycoords2=[]
f(y)=acos(cos(sqrt(y))+3*sin(sqrt(y))/sqrt(y))
for t in srange(0.01,40,step):
    if f(t).is_real():
        xcoords1+=[f(t).n(digits=4)]
        ycoords1+=[t]
        xcoords2+=[-f(t).n(digits=4)]
        ycoords2+=[t]

output = r""
output += r"\begin{tikzpicture}"
output += r"\begin{axis}[xlabel={$ka$},xtick distance={pi/2},"
output += r"xticklabels={,$-\pi$,$-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\dfrac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$},ytick={-10},"
output += r"ylabel={$E_k$},ylabel style={rotate=-90},trig format=rad,"
output += r"xmin=%f,xmax=%f,ymin= %f,ymax=%f]"%(LowerX,UpperX,LowerY, UpperY)
output += r"\addplot[only marks,mark options={mark size=.5pt},blue] coordinates {"
for i in range(0,len(xcoords1)-1):
    if (ycoords1[i])<LowerY or (ycoords1[i])>UpperY:
        output += r"(%f , inf) "%(xcoords1[i])
    else:
        output += r"(%f , %f) "%(xcoords1[i],ycoords1[i])
output += r"};"
output += r"\addplot[only marks,mark options={mark size=.6pt}, orange] coordinates {"
for i in range(0,len(xcoords2)-1):
    if (ycoords2[i])<LowerY or (ycoords2[i])>UpperY:
        output += r"(%f , inf) "%(xcoords1[i])
    else:
        output += r"(%f , %f) "%(xcoords2[i],ycoords2[i])
output += r"};"
output += r"\end{axis}"
output += r"\end{tikzpicture}"
\end{sagesilent}
\begin{center}
\sagestr{output}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

That's Python doing a lot of the work. A key part is here: `if f(t).is_real():`
Sage calculates the value of f(t) and includes it to the list of points if it is real. If it isn't real (because it's complex) then it does nothing with the calculation.

`only marks,mark options={mark size=.6pt}` tells the size of the point to be used and "only marks" is instructs it to not connect any points. The code:
`if (ycoords2[i])<LowerY or (ycoords2[i])>UpperY: output += r"(%f , inf) "%(xcoords1[i])` gets rid of points that don't fit within the screen plotting parameters by assigning the y-value to be infinite.

You can get a free [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) account to experiment with Sage and LaTeX. If it works for you then Sage can be downloaded onto your computer and connected to your LaTeX distribution.

**EDIT:** Had some time to tinker today. Just changing these lines
`output += r"\addplot[only marks,mark options={mark size=1pt},blue] coordinates {"` and
`output += r"\addplot[only marks,mark options={mark size=1pt}, orange] coordinates {"` results in bigger points which close the gap on top, though the gap on the bottom is still there.

[image]

Comment: By saying "I have to use two `\addplot` commands" I mean for each half, so there are a total of 4. Your solution does use only one command for each half. As for x=0 problem and the points get connected at gaps problem, with the programming capability of Sage I think I can fix them with some codes, but it just would be far less clean than a pure-pgfplots solution. I want to wait for other possible answers before accepting this.

Comment: @UlyssesZhan I edited my answer above. By making the points a little bit bigger the gap on top disappears and the gap on the bottom is mostly gone. Going out to 1.5 gets the bottom halves to barely touch but the plot is a little thicker than I'd like.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full soution, but an approach to it.

Instead of nesting `deg()` and `rad()`, try the `r` syntax that tells PGF that the value passed to trigonometric functions should be interpreted as radians. I also would recommend declaring a PGF function:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.18,
    /pgf/declare function={
        myfunc(\x)=rad(acos(cos(sqrt(\x) r)+3*sin(sqrt(\x) r)/sqrt(\x)));
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmax={pi},
        xmin={-pi},
        xlabel={$ka$},
        xtick distance={pi/2},
        xticklabels={,$-\pi$,$-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\dfrac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$},
        ymax=40,
        ymin=0,
        ytick={-10},
        ylabel={$E_k$},
        ylabel style={rotate=-90}
    ]
        \addplot[
            domain=0:40,
            smooth,
            samples=129,
            unbounded coords=jump 
        ] ({myfunc(x)},{x});
        \addplot[
            domain=0:40,
            smooth,
            samples=129,
            unbounded coords=jump 
        ] ({-1*myfunc(x)},{x});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are gaps near *x* = 0 which is probably an issue that can be solved by changing the sample size. I currently can't explain, why using `samples at` will (again?) raise an error.

Comment: Sorry, your MWE doesn't work ... it gives the same error as OP reported

Comment: Function is complex, so `pgfplots` can't draw it (it doesn't know how to drop out imaginary samples, to my opinion the function should be declared so, that values when x is negative, are not calculated; this meaning, that resulted function is not continues ...)

Comment: @Zarko You are right, the problem is not fully solved. But you could put a high number of samples, such as 4097 and at leat the gap at the top won't be visible anymore. Maybe this has really to be solved using other tools such as gnuplot or the suggested sagetex- I don't get any error when compiling this MWE.